# How to correct positions of annotations for graph (plt.bar + plt.plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got this data:

|  | month_dt | ses_canceled | ses_finished | all_ses | canceled_ptc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-02-01 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 28.57 |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 | 4 | 15 | 19 | 21.05 |
| 4 | 2021-06-01 | 4 | 23 | 27 | 14.81 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01 | 7 | 30 | 37 | 18.92 |
| 6 | 2021-08-01 | 6 | 53 | 59 | 10.17 |
| 7 | 2021-09-01 | 9 | 62 | 71 | 12.68 |
| 8 | 2021-10-01 | 11 | 90 | 101 | 10.89 |
| 9 | 2021-11-01 | 24 | 95 | 119 | 20.17 |
| 10 | 2021-12-01 | 30 | 131 | 161 | 18.63 |
| 11 | 2022-01-01 | 33 | 159 | 192 | 17.19 |
| 12 | 2022-02-01 | 34 | 189 | 223 | 15.25 |
| 13 | 2022-03-01 | 60 | 275 | 335 | 17.91 |
| 14 | 2022-04-01 | 75 | 391 | 466 | 16.09 |
| 15 | 2022-05-01 | 108 | 485 | 593 | 18.21 |
| 16 | 2022-06-01 | 90 | 585 | 675 | 13.33 |
| 17 | 2022-07-01 | 160 | 775 | 935 | 17.11 |
| 18 | 2022-08-01 | 216 | 1140 | 1356 | 15.93 |
| 19 | 2022-09-01 | 187 | 955 | 1142 | 16.37 |

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

ax1 = plt.bar(
    x=df7_2['month_dt'],
    height=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Finished sessions',
    edgecolor='black',
    linewidth=0,
    width=20,
    color='#3049BF'
)

ax2 = plt.bar(
    x=df7_2['month_dt'],
    height=df7_2['ses_canceled'],
    bottom=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Canceled sessions',
    edgecolor='black',
    linewidth=0,
    width=20,
    color='#BF9530'
)

secax = ax.twinx()
secax.set_ylim(min(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])-10, max(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])*1.5)
ax3 = plt.plot(
    df7_2['month_dt'],
    df7_2['canceled_ptc'],
    color='#E97800',
    label='Canceled sessions, ptc'
)

columns = ['ses_finished', 'ses_canceled', 'canceled_ptc']
colors = ['b', 'y', 'black']

for col, c in zip(columns, colors):
    for x, y in zip(df7_2['month_dt'], df7_2[col]):
        # list with quantiles for data
        lst = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
        describe_nearest = []
        [describe_nearest.append(df7_2[col].quantile(el, interpolation='nearest')) for el in lst]
        describe_nearest.append(df7_2[col].values[-1::][0])
        # add annotation if value in quantiles list
        if y in describe_nearest:
            label = '{:.0f}'.format(y)
            plt.annotate(
                label,
                (x, y),
                textcoords='offset points',
                xytext=(0, 0),
                ha='center',
                color=c
            )

ax.grid(False)
secax.grid(False)

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = secax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = h1 + h2
labels = l1 + l2

ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: plt.show]
How to correct positions of annotations?
Values for bars should be inside bars, values for plot near line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the high level `plt.bar`, `plt.plot`, and `plt.annotate`- you'll need to rely on the `Axes` level methods to have fine grained control over where you're adding these things.

Essentially `plt.annotate` will always use the "active" (most recently created) `Axes`. So your labels are always being plotted onto the Axes that the line is on.

We can use the `Axes` level methods, and then use a dictionary to track.

---

I also added a `patheffect` to help separate the text from the background as sometimes to colors made it hard to read the text. The `patheffect` adds an outline of color around the text, feel free to remove.

edit: to have your stacked labels appear at the top you'll need to calculate their heights (or grab them from the bar container). The broader issue you're hitting here is that you are attempting to do too much in 1 loop. The bars should be labelled separately from the lines so that they can have different arguments passed to them.

```py
data = {
    'all_ses': [3, 3, 7, 19, 27, 37, 59, 71, 101, 119, 161, 192, 223, 335, 466, 593, 675, 935, 1356, 1142],
    'canceled_ptc': [
        0.0, 0.0, 28.57, 21.05, 14.81, 18.92, 10.17, 12.68, 10.89, 20.17, 18.63,
        17.19, 15.25, 17.91, 16.09, 18.21, 13.33, 17.11, 15.93, 16.37
    ],
    'month_dt': [
        '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01',
        '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01',
        '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
        '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-09-01'
    ],
    'ses_canceled': [0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 9, 11, 24, 30, 33, 34, 60, 75, 108, 90, 160, 216, 187],
    'ses_finished': [3, 3, 5, 15, 23, 30, 53, 62, 90, 95, 131, 159, 189, 275, 391, 485, 585, 775, 1140, 955]
}

from pandas import DataFrame

df7_2 = DataFrame(data).astype({'month_dt': 'datetime64[ns]'})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patheffects import Normal, Stroke

fig, bar_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))
line_ax = bar_ax.twinx()

finished_bars = bar_ax.bar(
    x=df7_2['month_dt'],
    height=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Finished sessions',
    edgecolor='black',
    linewidth=0,
    width=20,
    color='#3049BF'
)

cancelled_bars = bar_ax.bar(
    x=df7_2['month_dt'],
    height=df7_2['ses_canceled'],
    bottom=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Canceled sessions',
    edgecolor='black',
    linewidth=0,
    width=20,
    color='#BF9530'
)

line_ax.set_ylim(min(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])-10, max(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])*1.5)
line_ax.plot(
    df7_2['month_dt'],
    df7_2['canceled_ptc'],
    color='#E97800',
    label='Canceled sessions, ptc'
)

columns = ['ses_finished', 'ses_canceled', 'canceled_ptc']
colors = [('b', 'white'), ('y', 'gainsboro'), ('black', 'white')]

ax_map = {
    'ses_finished': bar_ax,
    'ses_canceled': bar_ax,
    'canceled_ptc': line_ax,
}

for col, (c, stroke_c) in zip(columns, colors):
    for x, y in zip(df7_2['month_dt'], df7_2[col]):
        # list with quantiles for data
        lst = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
        describe_nearest = []
        [describe_nearest.append(df7_2[col].quantile(el, interpolation='nearest')) for el in lst]
        describe_nearest.append(df7_2[col].values[-1::][0])

        # add annotation if value in quantiles list
        if y in describe_nearest:
            if col == 'ses_canceled':
                y = y + df7_2.loc[df7_2['month_dt'] == x, 'ses_finished'].squeeze()
            label = '{:.0f}'.format(y)
            ax_map[col].annotate(
                label,
                (x, y),
                textcoords='offset points',
                xytext=(0, 0),
                ha='center',
                color=c,
                path_effects=[Stroke(linewidth=1, foreground=stroke_c), Normal()]
            )

bar_ax.grid(False)
line_ax.grid(False)

h1, l1 = bar_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = line_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = h1 + h2
labels = l1 + l2

bar_ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want to completely fix overlapping labels, you're going to need to reach somewhat deeper into matplotlib. We need to essentially  calculate the size of the text and compare that to the height of the bar and compare them.

I've also broken apart your single loop. This will make the code easier to revisit and introduce changes. Typically for plotting it is always best to be as verbose as possible because that gives you the most control over changing things in future iterations of the plot.

```py
data = {
    'all_ses': [3, 3, 7, 19, 27, 37, 59, 71, 101, 119, 161, 192, 223, 335, 466, 593, 675, 935, 1356, 1142],
    'canceled_ptc': [
        0.0, 0.0, 28.57, 21.05, 14.81, 18.92, 10.17, 12.68, 10.89, 20.17, 18.63,
        17.19, 15.25, 17.91, 16.09, 18.21, 13.33, 17.11, 15.93, 16.37
    ],
    'month_dt': [
        '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-06-01',
        '2021-07-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-10-01', '2021-11-01',
        '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
        '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01', '2022-07-01', '2022-08-01', '2022-09-01'
    ],
    'ses_canceled': [0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 9, 11, 24, 30, 33, 34, 60, 75, 108, 90, 160, 216, 187],
    'ses_finished': [3, 3, 5, 15, 23, 30, 53, 62, 90, 95, 131, 159, 189, 275, 391, 485, 585, 775, 1140, 955]
}

from pandas import DataFrame, isna

df7_2 = (
    DataFrame(data).astype({'month_dt': 'datetime64[ns]'})
    .set_index('month_dt')
    .drop(columns='all_ses')
)

# precalculate all quantiles & values that need to be labelled
quantiles = df7_2.quantile([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], numeric_only=True, interpolation='nearest')
to_label = df7_2.apply(lambda s: s.isin(quantiles[s.name]))
labels = df7_2.where(to_label)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patheffects import Normal, Stroke

fig, bar_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 6))
line_ax = bar_ax.twinx()

finished_bars = bar_ax.bar(
    x=df7_2.index,
    height=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Finished sessions',
    width=20,
    color='#3049BF'
)

# from the bottom row of bars, we need to add the quantile labels
#  we need to capture those labels (in a dictionary) so that we can use them as a height
#  basis for the next layer of bar labels
bar_labels = {}
for (month, value), rect in zip(labels['ses_finished'].items(), finished_bars):
    if isna(value):
        continue
    center_x, _ = rect.get_center()

    bar_labels[month] = bar_ax.annotate(
        f'{value:.0f}',
        (center_x, rect.get_y() + rect.get_height()),
        textcoords='offset points',
        xytext=(0, 1),
        ha='center',
        color=rect.get_facecolor(),
        path_effects=[Stroke(linewidth=.5, foreground='white'), Normal()]
    )
fig.canvas.draw()

cancelled_bars = bar_ax.bar(
    x=df7_2.index,
    height=df7_2['ses_canceled'],
    bottom=df7_2['ses_finished'],
    label='Canceled sessions',
    width=20,
    color='#BF9530'
)

for (month, value), rect in zip(labels['ses_canceled'].items(), cancelled_bars):
    if isna(value):
        continue

    center_x, _ = rect.get_center()
    existing_label = bar_labels.get(month)
 
    # if there is an existing text label for the 'ses_finished'
    #   we need take special care that the label for 'ses_canceled'
    #   does not overlap.
    if existing_label is None:
        label_top = 0
    else:
        label_top = (
            bar_ax.transData.inverted()
            .transform(existing_label.get_window_extent())
            .flat[-1]
        )

    bar_y = max(rect.get_y() + rect.get_height(), label_top)
    bar_labels[month] = bar_ax.annotate(
        f'{value:.0f}',
        (center_x, bar_y),
        textcoords='offset points',
        xytext=(0, 2),
        ha='center',
        color=rect.get_facecolor(),
        path_effects=[Stroke(linewidth=.5, foreground='gainsboro'), Normal()]
    )

line_ax.set_ylim(min(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])-10, max(df7_2['canceled_ptc'])*1.5)
line_ax.plot(
    df7_2.index,
    df7_2['canceled_ptc'],
    color='#E97800',
    label='Canceled sessions, ptc'
)
for month, value in df7_2['canceled_ptc'].dropna().items():
    line_ax.annotate(
        f'{value:.0f}',
        (month, value),
        textcoords='offset points',
        xytext=(0, 0),
        ha='center',
        color='black',
        path_effects=[Stroke(linewidth=.8, foreground='white'), Normal()]
    )

bar_ax.grid(False)
line_ax.grid(False)

h1, l1 = bar_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = line_ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

handles = h1 + h2
labels = l1 + l2

bar_ax.legend(handles, labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. But there's one thing need to improve. Any annotates for 'ses_canceled' needed to set higher. I think it's necessary to add  ses_finished values in xytext(0, *put values here*) in ax_map[col].annotate. I can't figure out, how to do it.

Comment: just updated with an edit. This needs some refactoring at this point because a lot of the logic is tangled up. I'll see if I can rewrite this quickly (time permitting). If not, the code works as is with the update.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that this issue has been resolved, however there will still be cases of overlapping text labels. So I've also included a refactoring of your code to introduce a fix to that as well. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I think I'll turn it into function later. =)